# Click on disabled Bootstrap radio button group buttons will remove the active from current

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3 and Angular 1.5 to present the radio button group on a page

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default" ng-click="changeAvailable(day.item[0],1)" ng-class="{1:'active'}[day.item[0].available]">
        <input type="radio" name="availabe[{{$index}}]" ng-checked="day.item[0].available==1" ng-model="day.item[0].available" ng-value="1">Workday
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default disabled" ng-click="changeAvailable(day.item[0],2)" ng-class="{2:'active'}[day.item[0].available]">
        <input type="radio" name="availabe[{{$index}}]" disabled="disabled" ng-checked="day.item[0].available==2" ng-model="day.item[0].available" ng-value="2">Break
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default" ng-click="changeAvailable(day.item[0],0)" ng-class="{0:'active'}[day.item[0].available]">
        <input type="radio" name="availabe[{{$index}}]" ng-checked="day.item[0].available==0" ng-model="day.item[0].available" ng-value="0">Dayoff
    </label>
</div>
```

I need to disable some of the buttons. So I add `class="disabled"` to `label` and `disabled="disabled"` to `input`.

Every thing looks find until I click on the disabled button. The current checked button is no more with `active` style. So I can't tell which button is active now.

I even checked the bootstrap official site example and also has this problem.

Does anyone know a solution about how to disabled a button entirely?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

you can add to css file :

```
.disabled {  pointer-events: none; }
```

or directly in element

```
<label class="btn btn-default disabled" style="pointer-events:none">
```

[Your issue at github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16703)
see also
[Remove pointer-events:none from .disabled](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17703)

Comment: This helped me. It might be the best answer.